# pre_save django model update fith celery shared_task

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery

I have Project model

```
class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    logo = models.ImageField(validators=[validate_image_size], blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And i want to compress logo field with reciever

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Project)
def compress_project_logo(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    compress_image.apply_async((instance.id,))
```

with shared_task

```
@shared_task
def compress_image(project_id):
    from api.models import Project
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=project_id)
    compressed_image = Image.open(project.logo)
    compressed_image = compressed_image.convert("RGB")
    compressed_image = ImageOps.exif_transpose(compressed_image)

    image_io = BytesIO()
    compressed_image.save(image_io, "JPEG", quality=70)
    project.logo = InMemoryUploadedFile(image_io, "ImageField", project.logo.file.name, "image/jpeg", sys.getsizeof(image_io), None)
    project.save()
```

And when i'm saving Project model through django admin i take this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-02-28 10:27:45   

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
  R = retval = fun(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 731, in __protected_call__
  return self.run(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/code/api/tasks/compress.py", line 14, in compress_image
  project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=project_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 19, in get_object_or_404
  return \_get_object_or_404(queryset, \*filter_args, \*\*filter_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 78, in get_object_or_404
  raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model.\_meta.object_name)
django.http.response.Http404: No Project matches the given query.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the transaction.atomic decorator I think on the `save` method

Comment: why do you think it's a problem

Comment: the `pre_save` signal is emitted inside the `save` method before the transaction is committed and your instance has no pk...

Comment: it still doesn't work when i deleted @transaction.atomic

Comment: Have you checked the id value in the receiver function?

Comment: yeah, in reciever func Project.objects.filter(id=instance.id).exists() is exists,
but in shared_task there is the same id, but Project.objects.filter(id=instance.id).exists() doesn't exists